# Using OSX system keychain from a daemon

Tags: macos, keychain

I have a daemon that needs to run as root and is started by launchd.  This daemon needs to store some user supplied credentials so I have it writing them to the System keychain using SecKeychainOpen and similar functions.

I'm pretty sure that since this runs as root I have to use the System keychain (since using a user's login keychain is not correct as this doesn't run as a normal user).

My installer loads this into launchd using launchctl at the end of the install.  The problem is that it doesn't actually start until after a reboot.  I had OnLOad set as true in the plist, but it appears that when using the system keychain I need to the reboot for it to work.

I was wondering if anyone knows of some way to deal with this since it would be a much better user experience if a reboot was not necessary.  So to be clear, can I programatically access the System keychain from a daemon using launchd without a reboot?

Thanks for any advice or ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I eventually figured out that my problem wasn't what I thought it was at all, I figure I should put the resolution to it up here.

It turns out (despite what I read on a few sites) that it is perfectly OK to programatically access the System keychain with a daemon using launchd without a reboot.  Just load the plist in the normal way (with root permission of course) and it all works.

My issue was the my postinstall script was never being run and was actually never even included in my .pkg installer when building on certain macs.  Apparently, if you do not have PackageMaker.app installed, macports will still make a dmg with an installer for you, but the installer is a directory rather than the proper single file and it may lack certain parts (such as my postinstall script).

PackageMaker.app can be found on the Apple Developer site in the Xcode AuxTools package (it then needs to be put in either /Applications or somewhere else macports can find it).